# Java: Calling a method on supertype does not use the subtype's implementation

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a problem with the sample of code below :

```
public abstract class PetBuilder<T extends PetBuilder<T>> {

  String name;
  int age;

  public T name(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public T age(String age) { this.age = age; }

  public T copy(Pet pet) {
    this.name = pet.name;
    this.age = pet.age;
  }

  public abstract Pet build();

}

public class CatBuilder extends PetBuilder<CatBuilder> {

  String color;

  public CatBuilder color(String color) { this.color = color; }  

  @Override
  public CatBuilder copy(Cat cat) {
    super.copy(cat);
    this.color = cat.color;
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public Cat build() {
    return new Cat(this);
  }

}

public abstract class Pet {

  protected String name;
  protected int age;

  Pet(PetBuilder builder) {
    this.name = builder.name;
    this.age = builder.age;
  }

  public abstract PetBuilder builder();

  public Pet withAge(int age) {
    return this.builder().copy(this).age(age).build();
  }

}

public class Cat extends Pet {

  private String color;

  Cat(CatBuilder builder) {
    super(builder);
    this.color = color;
  }

  @Override
  public CatBuilder builder() { return new CatBuilder(); }

  @Override
  public Cat withAge(int age) {
    return (Cat) super.withAge(age);
  }

}
```

When I execute the following code :

```
Cat felix = new CatBuilder().age(5).name("Felix").color("black").build();
felix = felix.withAge(6);
```

I end up with an instance of `Cat` (felix) whose color is `null` and not "black".

When inspecting with the debugger it seems that the method `copy()` of the class `CatBuilder` is never called even if the underlying object returned by `this.builder()` is a `CatBuilder` instance.

Is there a way to make this work so that I don't have to duplicate all the `withSomething()` methods in the child classes of `Pet` ?

Comment: The `@Override` at `copy()` should have created a compile error. Anyway, you need to do   `@Override  public CatBuilder copy(Pet cat) {` you can't change parametertypes when overriding.

Comment: Thanks @k5_ for the comment, I guess I was missing that `@Override` on my real code !